# Angular $resource POSTS $promise and $resolved to server on $save

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, resources, save

I am having trouble with `$resource` on one of my angular projects. All of a sudden it has started to mess up the objects that are sent to the server on `$save`.

Calls to `$save` on `$resource` objects does not strip away `$resolved` and `$promise` from the JSON data that is posted to my server.

The resource behaves like normal except this.

So If i were to call `$save` on an article -> this is what's actually being sent to the server:

```
{
    "id":999,
    "title":"test 2",
    "text":"",
    "file":null,
    "url":null,
    "pdato":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "author_id":0,
    "status":0,
    "lang":"",
    "parent":0,
    "$promise":{},
    "$resolved":true
}
```

The two last properties are the problem. I've never had this problem on other projects. Is it true that angular filters the resource object through `angular.toJson` before it sends it to the server, and this operation is supposed to remove the `$promise`/`$resolved` properties?

When I do a `console.log(angular.toJson(article));` (article is a fetched resource object) - it also logs the `$promise` and `$resolved` properties.

What can cause this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had a different version of angular-resource than angular.
Changed my dependencies versions in bower.json to this:

```
"angular": "~1.3.0",
"angular-resource": "~1.3.0" // this was ~1.2.0
```